# Repeater Control : Move individual item

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, repeater

I have a repeater control binded to a generic `List<>`.

The repeaters' items are all in its own `<div>` tag, so it gives a good block visual effect, as well as a standard placeholder for all the items.

With custom sorting, I have been able to arrange the results among its own standard, but now I need something that isn't standard.

I need to be able to take a selected item in a `<div>` block, and move it either to the bottom  or the top of the repeaters' item list.

Is there any way I am able to do this? Either by binding, or using the repeaters' `repeater_ItemDataBound()` method?

*The code is quite long.. So I will post what I think would be the 'need to know'.*

**Populating the generic list**

```
                        while (rdr.Read())
                        {
                            challenge.Add(new ChallengeList
                                {
                                    GameName = rdr["gameName"].ToString(),
                                    CreatorName = rdr["creatorName"].ToString(),
                                    MediatorName = rdr["mediatorName"].ToString(),
                                    ChallengeID = rdr["challengeId"].ToString(),
                                    ChallengeAccepted = rdr["accepted"].ToString(),
                                    MatchDate = DateTime.Parse(rdr["matchDate"].ToString()).ToString("dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm")
                                });
                        }
```

**-Same Method- Sorting the data, then binding**

```
    switch (sort)
    {
        case "name":
            Comparison<ChallengeList> name = ChallengeList.CompareGameName;
            challenge.Sort(name);
            break;

        case "date":
            Comparison<ChallengeList> date = ChallengeList.CompareDate;
            challenge.Sort(date);
            break;

        case "status":
            Comparison<ChallengeList> status = ChallengeList.CompareStatus;
            challenge.Sort(status);
            break;
    }

    rptChallenges.DataSource = challenge;
    rptChallenges.DataBind();
```

**Generic List Class (With sorting)**

```
/// <summary>
/// Class ChallengeList
/// With sorting
/// </summary>
public class ChallengeList
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Compares the name of the game.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="game1">The game1.</param>
    /// <param name="game2">The game2.</param>
    /// <returns>System.Int32.</returns>
    public static int CompareGameName(ChallengeList game1, ChallengeList game2)
    {
        return String.Compare(game1.GameName, game2.GameName, StringComparison.Ordinal);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Compares the status.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="status1">The status1.</param>
    /// <param name="status2">The status2.</param>
    /// <returns>System.Int32.</returns>
    public static int CompareStatus(ChallengeList status1, ChallengeList status2)
    {
        return string.Compare(status1.ChallengeAccepted, status2.ChallengeAccepted, StringComparison.Ordinal);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Compares the date.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="date1">The date1.</param>
    /// <param name="date2">The date2.</param>
    /// <returns>System.Int32.</returns>
    public static int CompareDate(ChallengeList date1, ChallengeList date2)
    {
        return string.Compare(date1.MatchDate, date2.MatchDate, StringComparison.Ordinal);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Compares the date reverse.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="date2">The date2.</param>
    /// <param name="date1">The date1.</param>
    /// <returns>System.Int32.</returns>
    public static int CompareDateReverse(ChallengeList date2, ChallengeList date1)
    {
        return string.Compare(date1.MatchDate, date2.MatchDate, StringComparison.Ordinal);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the name of the game.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The name of the game.</value>
    public string GameName { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the name of the creator.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The name of the creator.</value>
    public string CreatorName { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the name of the mediator.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The name of the mediator.</value>
    public string MediatorName { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the challenge ID.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The challenge ID.</value>
    public string ChallengeID { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the challenge accepted.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The challenge accepted.</value>
    public string ChallengeAccepted { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the match date.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The match date.</value>
    public string MatchDate { get; set; }
}
```

**Real-world application of my question**
If there is a 'stickied' match - it must appear on top of the matches regardless of date, status or name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend that you order the data in your list before you see ditto the repeater.  If this is not possible given structure of your data and/or the item template of the repeater, could you please include samples of the data and the repeater so that we may help further?

**EDIT after asker posted code**

rather than setting challenge as the data source for the repeater you should separate all the items that need to be on the top of the list into a new list and then append the other other items to the end of the top items.

something like this:

```
var topItmes = new List<ChallengeList>();
var otherItmes = new List<ChallengeList>();

foreach (var item in challenge)
{
    if(/*item needs to be on top*/)
    {
        topItmes.Add(item);
    }
    else
    {
        otherItmes.Add(item);
    }
}

topItmes.AddRange(otherItmes);
```

depending on what the criteria is for an item to be on the top, you may be able to use a LINQ expression to simplify this code.

Comment: Sorry for long response time.. Never saw the update. I can see the process of this code.. Will try asap.